# Russian Roulette probability when chamber is spun randomly every turn

Tags: probability

I'm trying to wrap my brain around this question. I have the answer, but I don't understand it.

Russian Roullette is played with 1 bullet in a pistol with 6 chambers. 5 Chambers are empty. 6 Players takes turn to shoot themselves in the head. Game stop when someone is dead.

A stipulation is added so that **after every turn, the bullet chambers are re-spun**. So, there's still probability that no one dies in this game.

The question is **which player has the most chance of survival** (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th or 6th) ?

At a first glance, each player has the same amount of probability of survival, 5/6.
Since the game stop when someone is dead, so the probability of survival for each player requires the previous player to be alive. Therefore probability of survival for each player is:

1. 5/6 = .83
2. (5/6) ^ 2 = .69
3. (5/6) ^ 3 = .58
4. (5/6) ^ 4 = .48
5. (5/6) ^ 5 = .40
6. (5/6) ^ 6 = .33
   Making the 1st player most likely to survive.

However, the answer to this problem is looking at it from Probability of death perspective.

Probability of death for player:

1. 1/6 = .17
2. 5/6 * 1/6 = .14
3. (5/6)^2 * 1/6 = .12
4. (5/6)^3 * 1/6 = .097
5. (5/6)^4 * 1/6 = .08
6. (5/6)^5 * 1/6 = .07
   Making the last player least likely to die ~ most likely to be alive.

shouldn't the 2 ways above(probability of surviving and dead) be complementary? but other than the first player, they probability of player 2 through 6 are not complementary.

what's wrong with the probability of survival calculation? it seems to make sense.

Comment: Your survival math is wrong.  You are computing the probability that *everybody* up to position $k$ survives, but $k$ also survives if somebody dies ahead of them.

Comment: Note:  Your intuition is good.  Done correctly, survival probability plus death probability should be $1$.

Comment: @lulu if a player  is dead, the game stops. So, it's not possible for player 3 and 4 to continue if player 2 is dead.

Comment: Exactly.  So in that situation, players $3$ and up survive.  They certainly don't die (at least, not from the game).

Comment: should say:  if you are using "survive" to specifically mean that they take a shot but it's empty, that's fine but in that case the situations are not complementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you calculated in your first calculation is the probability $P(\bar1,\bar2,\bar3,...)=(5/6)^n$, which is not the probability that player $n$ dies, but the probability that nobody dies after the $n$th round.

The probability of player one dying is
$$
p=P(1)={1\over 6}
$$
The probability of player two dying is
$$
P(2)=P(2|1)P(1)+P(2|\bar1)P(\bar1)\\
=P(2|\bar1)\times P(\bar1)\\
=p(1-p)\\
={1\over 6}{5\over6}\\
={5\over36}
$$
since the probability of 2 dying if 1 dies, $P(2|1)=0$.

Similarly $P(3)=P(3|\bar2)P(\bar2)=(1-p)^2p=25/216$, and so on.

The probability that all the players survive is $(1-p)^6=(5/6)^6={15626\over46656}\approx\frac13$.

Comment: I was calculating the probability of ALL PLAYERS survive!!! THANK YOU!!! Now it makes sense!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, a player not losing does not require that no previous player has lost.

> Which player has the most chance of survival?

In the general case suppose, we have $n$ players and $n$ chambers.

On the $i$th spin, there is a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance that the game ends and an $\frac{n - 1}{n}$ chance that it does not. If the game does not end, then the player taking the $(i+1)$st turn has the same probability of losing that the player taking the $i$th turn did before taking their turn, so the probability $s_j$ that the $j$th player, $j > 1$, loses satisfies
$$s_j = \frac{n - 1}{n} s_{j - 1}.$$
In particular, $s_1 > \cdots > s_n$, that is, player $n$ has the greatest probability of survival.